# Can Guava Hashtable have columns with different data types?

Tags: java, hashtable, guava

I need create a Guava Hashtable and store integer and string values in different columns. Can this be done with guava  Hashtable ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look in [Table documentation](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Table.html) ([HashBasedTable](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/HashBasedTable.html) is only an implementation of `Table` - "...which is essentially backed by a `HashMap<R, HashMap<C, V>>`...")

A single `Table<R, C, V>` object represents a single mapping between a row key `R`, a column key `C` and a value `V` and as so, you can have only columns from a single type on a particular `Table` object.

To mixture columns you can create two table objects with shares the same keys:
    Table tableStringCol = HashBasedTable.create();
    table.put(1, "doc_name", "Bill");
    Table tableIntegerCol = HashBasedTable.create();
    table.put(1, "doc_count", 10);
    table.put(1, "doc_size", 15);

You can also use a single `Table` object which have only `String` columns and then when fetching the values, make a conversion from the relevant columns into `Integer`.
You can read more about Guava's `Table` [here](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#table)

Comment: It seems I am missing something still. Here is the pseudocode am working upon https://ibb.co/gaCAOm  and here is the table am trying to create https://ibb.co/j3qapR .. .  TO create just the first row of my table I require those 3 LOC and it seems datatype of all values need to be same. Can you guide pls?

Comment: I misunderstood your question. I've updated the answer.

Comment: So I need to create 2 tables sharing the same Pry Key. Now when I would want to retrieve details for Row 1 then I would have to fetch from both the tables. This solution is helpful. I cannot go with the 2nd  approach suggested  by you i.e. to use a single Table object because I need update the values of doc_count and doc_size in every call to this table.  Last query I got: Am basically trying to create a lookup table but in every call to the table, 2 of the columns values <doc_count & doc_size> would be updated and the table would be called for approx 2million times in one code run.

Comment: My Question is should I go with RDBMS table for above? or Hashtable would be fine?

Comment: A max of 20GB Heap can be allocated in the machine am trying to run this code. Considering network costs involved in RDBMS call, I had been thinking to use Guava HashTable

Comment: EDIT: Its not a lookup table since am upadting the columns

Comment: Why won't the second approach work ? You can still update it on every call (as long as fetching and updating is a single transaction). Using `HashBasedTable` sounds reasonable, but keep in mind that it isn't synchronized.

Comment: I have to update values docSize and docCount in the table itself in every single transaction. So string being the dataType I cannot update values in table .. I assume you have been suggesting me to update the values in java after I fetch from table.. Right?

Comment: Right, fetching the result, convert to integer and then update it